# Django-filter: ModelChoiceFilter with request.user based queryset

Tags: python, django, django-filter

I have a Django class based ListView listing objects. These objects can be filtered based on locations. Now I want that the location ModelChoiceFilter only lists locations which are relevant to the current user. Relevant locations are the locations he owns. How can I change the queryset?

```
# models.py
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from rules.contrib.models import RulesModel
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _


class Location(RulesModel):
    name = models.CharField(_("Name"), max_length=200)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        verbose_name=_("Owner"),
        related_name="location_owner",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        help_text=_("Owner can view, change or delete this location."),
    )

class Object(RulesModel):
    name = models.CharField(_("Name"), max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField(_("Description"), blank=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        verbose_name=_("Owner"),
        related_name="location_owner",
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        help_text=_("Owner can view, change or delete this location."),
    )
    location = models.ForeignKey(
        Location,
        verbose_name=_("Location"),
        related_name="object_location",
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
```

This is my current filters.py file which shows **all** the locations to the user.

```
# filters.py
from .models import Object
import django_filters

class ObjectFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Object
        fields = ["location", ]
```

This is the view which by default shows objects the user owns. It's possible to filter further by location. But the location drop-down shows too many entries.

```
# views.py
from django.views.generic import ListView
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from .models import Object
from .filters import ObjectFilter

class ObjectListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Object
    paginate_by = 10

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Object.objects.filter(owner=self.request.user)
        filterset = ObjectFilter(self.request.GET, queryset=queryset)
        return filterset.qs

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ObjectListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        filterset = ObjectFilter(self.request.GET, queryset=self.queryset)
        context["filter"] = filterset
        return context
```

### My last attempt

I've tried to tweak the filters.py with adding a ModelChoiceFilter, but it ends up with an **AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'request'**.

```
# filters.py
from .models import Object
import django_filters

def get_location_queryset(self):
    queryset = Location.objects.filter(location__owner=self.request.user)
    return queryset

class ObjectFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    location = django_filters.filters.ModelChoiceFilter(queryset=get_location_queryset)

    class Meta:
        model = Object
        fields = ["location", ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe a few different issues are at play here. First, as per the [django-filter docs](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/filters.html?highlight=ModelChoiceFilter#modelchoicefilter), when a callable is passed to `ModelChoiceFilter`, it will be invoked with `Filterset.request` as its only argument. So your `filters.py` would need to be rewritten like so:

```py
# filters.py
from .models import Object
import django_filters

def get_location_queryset(request): # updated from `self` to `request`
    queryset = Location.objects.filter(location__owner=request.user)
    return queryset

class ObjectFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    location = django_filters.filters.ModelChoiceFilter(queryset=get_location_queryset)

    class Meta:
        model = Object
        fields = ["location", ]
```

This is half of the puzzle. I believe the other issue is in your view. `django-filter` has view classes that handle passing requests to filtersets, but this does not happen automatically using Django's generic `ListView`. Try updating your view code to something like this:

```py
# views.py
from django_filters.views import FilterView

class ObjectListView(LoginRequiredMixin, FilterView): # FilterView instead of ListView
    model = Object
    filterset_class = ObjectFilter
```

This should take care of passing the request for you.

Also note that, as per the django-filter docs linked above, your queryset should handle the case when `request` is `None`. I've personally never seen that happen in my projects, but just FYI.

As an alternative, if you don't want to use `FilterView`, I believe the code in your example is almost there:

```py
# views.py alternative
class ObjectListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Object
    paginate_by = 10

    def get_queryset(self):
        filterset = ObjectFilter(self.request)
        return filterset.qs
```

I think this would also work with the `filters.py` I specified above.

Comment: Hi @Monks, thanks a lot for your input! It started to work after I've switched from ListView to FilterView, only returned the queryset in `def get_query_set(self)` and removed the complete `def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):` method.

Comment: Ah, yeah, that makes sense. I forgot to consider how your existing `get_queryset` and `get_context_data` would interact with `FilterView`. Glad you got it working!

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this code:

```
def get_location_queryset(self):
    queryset = Location.objects.filter(location__owner=self.request.user)
    return queryset
```

is that it is a function based view, you added `self` as an argument, and tried to access `request` which does not exist in context of `self` since `self` value is undefined to us

What i would do to filter out location based on user by creating a class based view for location filtering

```
class LocationView(ListView):
      def get_queryset(self):
          return Location.objects.filter(owner=self.request.user)
```

in filters.py:

```
class ObjectFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    location = django_filters.filters.ModelChoiceFilter(queryset=LocationView.as_view())

    class Meta:
        model = Object
        fields = ["location", ]
```

Comment: I tried to use my existing LocationListView(), but after applying it as you described I get an *ImportError: cannot import name 'LocationListView' from partially initialized module 'inventory.views' (most likely due to a circular import) (/app/inventory/views.py)*.

Comment: You are importing file 1 to file 2, and file 2 to file 1, this is called "circular import", this is why you are getting the error.

Comment: Thanks @Ghazi, I was able to circle around the circular import issue. But now I get *AttributeError at /object/: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'user'*. Do you have an other proposal on how to get the queryset? Full implementation is available in my [GitHub repository](https://github.com/gldecurtins/objector/blob/main/inventory/views.py#L28). Last pushed version is without `location = django_filters.filters.ModelChoiceFilter(queryset=LocationListView.as_view())` in filters.py